# Rounding errors in Java

Tags: java, android

I'm having rounding issues in Java (i.e. with whole = 1387.583515625 the output is x = 5836 instead of 5835. I have searched the issue before and I've tried various of the answers but I still can't seem to get it yo work. Any ideas?

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".####");
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);

int x = Integer.parseInt(String.format(df.format(whole)).split("\\.")[1]);
```

Comment: Why would the output be 5835 if you require that it must be rounded up?

Comment: replace RoundingMode.CEILING by RoundingMode.FLOOR

Comment: oooooooh.... thanks. I feel stupid now.

Comment: @weston that abnormal value is because of DecimalFormat being used. Should have been DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###,##");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this table to decide what you want https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html

```
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly well explained in [this javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html).

You need to use `RoundingMode.DOWN` to get what you want, not  `RoundingMode.CEILING`.

[image]

Comment: You're welcome. If it is ok, please don't forget to mark your question as answered using the checkmark on the left. Happy coding !

Comment: This is an android question, better to reference the android documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/java/math/RoundingMode.html

Answer (score 1):

## [Be wary of the default locale!](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#default_locale)

> The default locale is not appropriate for machine-readable output.

You're machine reading this formatted output and the problem there is with `.split("\\.")` in that it assumes the decimal separator is `'.'`. The fact you specify `'.'` in the format is neither here nor there, that will get replaced with the separator from the culture.

## Alternative

You can fix by specifying the `Locale.US` culture, but I'd probably not use string formatting and splitting just to get some of the digits from a number:

Either:

```
int x = (int)((whole - (int)whole) * 10000);
```

Or:

```
int x = (int)(whole * 10000) % 10000;
```

And `Math.abs` if `whole` might be negative.